# Headers using EasyWsdl in Android Studio

Tags: android, soap, easywsdl

I'm attempting to create an android app that makes a **SOAP** request. I've tried several different libraries (**OkHTTP, kSoap2**) to help me with this, and am currently trying to make classes generated through **EasyWSDL** work.

I'm able to create and send the request, but I can't seem to add the headers that I need. I'm adding them thusly, in the code:

```
HeaderProperty hProp1 = new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +
            org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode("########:#######".getBytes()));
HeaderProperty hProp2 = new HeaderProperty("Username", "########");
HeaderProperty hProp3 = new HeaderProperty("Password", "########");

service.httpHeaders.add(hProp2);
service.httpHeaders.add(hProp3);
service.httpHeaders.add(hProp1);
```

But in the end, the request that's generated lacks these headers:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:v="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Happy to provide further detail if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I know, that this is old question but maybe I will help someone else. So httpHeaders collection is to add HTTP headers (not SOAP headers).

To add custom SOAP headers, the easiest way is to create a custom class which inherits from the generated service class. Then override createEnvelope method and set correct soap headers. In the code you should use this custom class to invoke a web service. Here is an example:

```
public class TestService extends BasicHttpBinding_IBodyArchitectAccessService
{
    @Override
    protected ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope createEnvelope() {
        ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope env= super.createEnvelope();
        env.headerOut = new org.kxml2.kdom.Element[2];
        org.kxml2.kdom.Element h = new org.kxml2.kdom.Element().createElement("","APIKey");
        h.addChild(org.kxml2.kdom.Node.TEXT, "123455677");

        org.kxml2.kdom.Element lang = new org.kxml2.kdom.Element().createElement("","Lang");
        lang.addChild(org.kxml2.kdom.Node.TEXT, "pl");

        env.headerOut[0]=h;
        env.headerOut[1]=lang;
        return env;
    }
}
```